# Reacting task waits before the detecting task notifies

Tags: c++, multithreading

Good day every developers, or engineers for a nice world,

I am coming back to you for a question about page 266 of "Effective Modern C++"

Doctor Scott Meyers writes at line 2 of the first paragraph :

" **It works regardless of whether the reacting task waits before the detecting task notifies** "

I am thinking on it , since a while, and I could not justify it.

**Is it possible you explain to me why exactly** ?

Usually https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

writes that we should wait on "wait" before receiving the notification. And in the example of Doctor Scott Meyers, we are not in this situation according to him.

So, I would be thankful someone explains to me that in details.

```
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;
bool flag(false);

....
{

std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(m);
flag=true;
}
cv.notify_one();


.....

and the reactig task :

...
{
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);

cv.wait(lk,[]{return flag;});

...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv.wait(lk,[]{return flag;});` is the key line here.

This is required to be equivalent to:

```
while(!pred())
{
    cv.wait(lk);
}
```

where `pred` is your line `[]{return flag;}`

Note here that the predicate is always checked before a wait is even considered. This means that if the first tasks completes and notifies no-one then that doesn't matter - the reactive task comes along, takes the lock and checks `flag` and seeing it set to true doesn't even try to do a `wait`.

The last thing to understand is that the predicate check and a subsequent wait if required are all performed whilst the lock is held so there can't be a race condition between the call to the predicate and the wait where the original thread can slip in.

Comment: According to Dr Scott Meyers page 265, the while is not equivalent in terms of performance

Comment: According to the solution with while you propose, it is very greedy in terms of energy. That's why he proposes this other solution. And it is what i try to understand

Comment: In fact my precise question is : "why is it possible the notify before the wait ?"

Comment: If we do the notify before the wait of the reactive task, how is it possible that the reactive task resumes ? it will be too late ... it is what i don't understand

Comment: Re, "The while is not equivalent in terms of performance." It is not required to have equivalent _performance_, but it _is_ required to behave in the same way as the explicit loop. The reacting task in the book example will _not_ await a notification if the predicate already was `true` before `cv.wait(...)` was called.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: @DanielKhoshnoudirad If you find this answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking the tick beside the post.